# JDK 1.6 compiled code call a JDK 1.5 compiled code. what errors will we see?

Tags: java, java-6, incompatibletypeerror

If a class compiled with JDK 1.6 calls another class compiled with JDK 1.5, what kind of errors will we see?

- Class Not found exception?
- Class cast exception?
- NoSuch method exception?

Answer (score 4):

You should encounter no problems doing this.  I have a code library with packages compiled with everything from 1.2 to 1.4 and have had absolutely no problems using it with applications compiled with Java 5 and Java 6.

Comment: thanks for answer. I should have specified the execution environment. If we execute JDK1.6 compiled code which calls JDK 1.5 compiled code execute in the JDK1.5 environment, then we should see errors though/

Comment: You can't run Java 6 compiled code with a Java 5 JVM - the byte code version is not compatible.  But it has nothing to do with whether it calls Java 5 compiled code or not.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the error '**Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**:" file name

1. Check for the file whether deploy in correct path in server or not.
2. If deploy correctly and still not picking then check the environment java version and Eclipse java version.Both should be matched.
3. If not matching then took the file from environment and recompile the java file in eclipse by setting the Eclipse compilation configuration changing to the Environment java version.
4. Deploy it in server and Enjoy.